# jquery php variable

Tags: php, jquery

I have a variable hard coded in to my html inside script tags like this(it calls meta information from a wordpress post and I've checked that the meta is being pulled)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var jg_product_price = "<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID , 'productprice' , true); ?>";
</script>
```

my jquery code reads;

```
.prepend('<span>'+jg_product_price+'</span>');
```

the html output is:

```
<span></span>
```

i.e an empty span

Is it something to do with the "'" in the var jg_product_price? Many thanks

Comment: well... what does `get_post_meta($post->ID , 'productprice' , true);` return?

Comment: if you alert or output the value of jg_product_price to the console, what value do you see?

Comment: if you look a the source of your page, does jg_product_price have anything in it?

Comment: what is the output in a script tag?

Comment: does <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID , 'productprice' , true); ?> return anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `jg_product_price` is empty. Have a look at

```
alert(jg_product_price);
```

or view the source code of the page. Make sure `get_post_meta($post->ID , 'productprice' , true);` is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the resulting page in Firebug (or whatever) and check what, if anything, the php actually outputs into the source.
2. Try hard coding the value: `var jg_product_price = "test";`.
3. Try hard coding the value in php: `var jg_product_price = "<?php echo "test2"; ?>"`.